# Символ переноса строки

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, c#

Всем привет.
Я решил на сайте сделать систему bb-кодов, т.е. менять написанное `[b]` в `<b>` и т.п.

Появился вопрос, когда речь зашла о теге `<br>`.  Не принято ведь писать `[br]` в bb-кодах, чтобы перенести предложение на следующую строку. Там просто люди нажимают `enter` и `<br>` появляется. Тогда какой мне символ заменять на `<br>`, чтобы все работало так, как все привыкли? Не хочется использовать чью-то готовую библиотеку, хочу сам сделать.

P.S: сайт на [asp.net](http://asp.net)

---

Спасибо за ответ, но у меня появилась проблема с этой `\n`. 
Когда я конвертирую обратно из html в бб-коды, то `\n` отображается как текст. Но я нашел выход, вместо нее применил вот это: `Environment.NewLine`. 
Все получилось, но, помимо этого, появилась еще одна проблема:

Если, опять же, конвертировать из html в бб-коды, то вместо `[b]` там `\[b\]`. 
Т.к. я применяю регулярные выражения для замены, и там мне приходилось писать `@"\[b\](.+?)\[b\]"`. Что делать?
можно конечно реплейсить этот символ `\` при обратной конвертации, но это как-то муторно.

---

короче, я сам на все ответил. Решил реплейснуть `\` на пустоту при обратной конвертации. Код получился достаточно компактным, чтобы оставить так как есть. Поэтому все готово, пока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Символ переноса строки - *\n*, именно этот символ надо заменять на *<br>*. Если я правильно понял вопрос, конечно.

Comment: а разве этот \n не будет воспринят как текст? в asp.net проекте. Например, если использовать функцию string.Replace

Comment: а если использовать функцию string.Replace, то из слова "beer" можно сделать слово "vodka" !

Comment: string.Replace("shurik", "алкоголик");